# Using objects in objects?

Tags: php, oop, class

Is it possible to use an object within an object? For example, I have a MySQL class which has every MySQL related method (connect, query, get rows...), and I'm making a new object called User, which will have methods such as login, logout, register etc... Is it possible to include my MySQL class, define an object and then run queries in my new object? If so, **HOW**?
For example:

```
class User{
    $m = new MySQL();
    function login($username, $password, $remember = false){
                $m->rQuery("SELECT * FROM users......");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pro Hint: *Pass* your database object to User rather than having User instantiate it itself. It reduces *coupling.* Check out [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it like this:

```
class User{
    private $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new MySQL();
    }

    function login($username, $password, $remember = false){
                $this->db->rQuery("SELECT * FROM users......");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use an object within an object?

Yes.

Use the `__construct` function to initialize any sub-objects that you need

Answer (score 2):

An answer that is very similar to the others, but with one - in my opinion, key - difference: rather than instantiating the dependency/dependencies *in* the constructor, pass them *to* the constructor:

```
class User
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Db $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users...");
    }
}
```

The benefits to this type of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) include:

1. It clearly demonstrates that the client/consumer class (`User`) has a dependency (`Db`).
2. Reduces coupling between the `User` class and the `Db` class. This helps significantly when [unit-testing](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/automating-tests.html) the `User` class. You can create a mock `Db` that performs as expected. Any test failures are then clearly attributable to the `User` class.

Of course, in order to instantiate a `User` object, you need to instantiate a `Db` object first. With a lot of dependencies for a single object or for a long chain of dependencies, this can be kind of a pain. In that case, it is helpful - but not required - to employ a Factory or a Dependency Injection Container to assist with this object creation.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcource and you can, but not in that way. What you can do is like that:

```
class User
{
    private $m = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->m = new MySQL();
    }

    function login($username, $password, $rememer = false)
    {
        $this->m->rQuery("SELECT * FROM users......");
    }
}
```

Comment: Old style constructor. I'd favor `__construct`.

Comment: The time of you downgrade I changed the constructor name. Please uprate again if you like

Comment: May can I know why am I downrated ?

Comment: There's still another bug in your code. As soon as you fix it, your answer will be almost the same as Vikk's...

Comment: I have fix my bug, and also, you know very whel that every person will give almost the same answer. Even you, if you answer that question, will seem your answer to my one and Vikk answer too. If you see the submit time, these answer posted at the same time, so, neither copy Vikk answer or Vikk copy my answer.

Comment: The original answer was indeed posted at the same time. But it contained two reasons for me to downvote the question. You've changed it, so now (6 minutes later) the answer is good, but same as Vikk's. I've removed the downvote, but I'm not going to upvote, because your answer has no additional value to the answer already posted.